# html css equal div height

Tags: html, css

I have one container div which contain 2 dynamic height (height haven't been set) divs side by side , those 2 divs are content divs , sometimes one div have more content than which cause to be more long from the other one , and those two divs have different color , in order to have Aesthetic page view i want those two divs to have equal height

how can i do this without involve javascript?

```
<div style="width:100px;border:1px solid black;">
    <div style="width:50px;background-color:blue;float:left;">a <br/> b</div>
    <div style="width:50px;background-color:red;float:left;">a</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

### live example : http://jsfiddle.net/Vbkhq/

in the example above you can see that the blue div is bigger than the red div because it contain more content , what i want to do is what ever content the other div have the both divs have equal height and be look with similar size.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display:table` property for this:

```
.parent{
    width:100px;
    display:table;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.child{
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
    display:table-cell;
}
.child + .child{background:red;}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/Vbkhq/7/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible without Javascript for this situation. But you can handle if you use tables.

Answer (score 0):

Or look into this:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks