# CSS equal height divs

Tags: css, html

I want the left column is the same height of the right column after processing a php form.
This is the html code:

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

I would like your help to set the css configuration!

```
.header, .footer{
text-align: center;
background-color: #777;
color: white;
border-style: dotted;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
width: 100%;
}

.footer{
text-align: center;
line-height: 100%;
float: left;
height: 5%;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.left{
border-style: dotted;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
background-color: #CCC;
float: left;
width: 11%;
min-height: 500px;
margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
height: 100%;
}

.right{
border-style: dotted;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
width: 88%;
float: right;
min-height: 500px;
margin: 2px -2px 2px 8px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
height: 100%;
}
```

I'm new in the languages ​​php / html / css.

I've looked at other topics, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I set a css, but it only worked for IE. Chrome and FF didn't work.

Oh, i want this working dynamically.
And without height limits in px. Only in %.

Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [html css equal div height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295680/html-css-equal-div-height)

Comment: the small element is supposed to be used for things like copyright.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/8Szh5/

I have added a large padding and an equally large negative margin to the left and right divs, then the container div which wraps around them both has overflow hidden.

**CSS**

```
.left{
padding-bottom: 99999px;
margin-bottom: -99999px;
/* more stuff */
}  

.right{
padding-bottom: 99999px;
margin-bottom: -99999px;
/* more stuff */
}

.container{
overflow: hidden;   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="left">
</div> <!-- end left -->

<div class="right">
</div> <!-- end right -->

</div> <!-- end container -->

<div class="footer">
</div> <!-- end footer -->
```

This technique works well cross-browser as well.

For simplicity I commented out some of your extra CSS. In this example I also removed your borders around these divs. Remember that borders acutally add extra width to the div, and so this can throw your width calculations off. If you need borders, check out the the [box-sizing: border-box method](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) which forces the border inside your div.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This approach will not work if you have an anchor to an href of an ID of an element further down in the #left or #right divs (out of initial view).  When you click on the anchor hyperlink, it will scroll the div to where the id of the anchor is, but the you will not be able to scroll back due to the padding/margins.

Comment: @codechurn the points you raise weren't a condition of the original question I answered. However if you want to start a jsfiddle that illustrates your point I would be happpy to look at it and see if I have any ideas.

Comment: here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agola/69nkv/6/) which demonstrates the problem.  Click on the hyperlink to the 10th paragraph.  Note that the scrollbar is not relative to the div which contains the problem.

Comment: Thanks @codechurn . In your specific case, maybe something like this is a better solution : Live: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/TBgVj/embedded/result/ , edit: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/TBgVj/ Good luck!

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar.  Thanks for the followup and hopefully it will save someone sometime when using the margin/padding approach :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the technique I use everytime I need 2 or more divs with equal height, I won't explain how it works Matthew James Taylor does a great job at it: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Hope this helps, it certainly have saved me from headaches a couple of times.

Comment: I've saw this example, but i couldn't transform this to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If using a table is out of the question, try this:

```
#container {
    display:flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-moz-flex;
}
```

This should expand the `#left` and `#right` boxes to fill the entire height of the container.

Comment: @Falmarri Which people should be using anyway but frustratingly aren't. If we pander to people who can't be bothered to upgrade, we'd be stuck in last milennium because of the 1% of people who still use IE7 or older...

Comment: @Kolink you cant do that if your client is asking for a website. Try to explain why it doesnt work on x browser, he dont want a excuse, just it working.

Comment: @Falmarri look my editions in the question. This is html and css. The can search in db mysql and it returns in table form to div right. But sometimes the table is bigger than div left. I want to set height for left equal right.

Comment: @Kolink: Flexbox isn't even supported in IE9. So sure, use it, I've actually used it before. But understand that the flexbox model is one of the newest features of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
.left, .right { height: 100%; }
.container { height: 400px; }
```

But you need to create a separated file just for the css and call it on the head of html.

Comment: só para entender.. O left é um menu e o right é o conteúdo com um formulário. Esse formulário é gerado e irá retornar uma tabela que pode ser de um tamanho maior do que o tamanho do left. E no caso right e left ficam com tamanhos diferentes. Queria igualar o tamanho após o retorno da tabela.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but in any case you can explicitly set the height of each div in your css:

```
.left {
   height: 300px;
   ...other attributes...
}
.right {
   height: 300px;
   ...other attributes...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Valentinos. But it isn't what i want. I know to set height. I want to maintain the proportion of the page after the user runs the form.

Answer (score 0):

somehow I found myself in the same situation with this original question of this topic..the simple and easiest solution I ended up to be the right answer is replied by "David Taiaroa" this fixed my problem perfectly!

Thank you **David Taiaroa**, you are life saver!

Comment: In this case, mark David's answer as accepted by clicking the green tick. And DO NOT post "thank you" comments as **answers**. You should post it as a comment (!!) under David's answer, and delete this one before getting some downvotes (which would decrease your reputation).